# "ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0 ... (size 2 is different from 1)"

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am just starting to learn Python/NumPy. I want to write a function which will apply an operation with 2 inputs and 1 output and a given weight matrix i.e two NumPy arrays of shape  (2,1)  and should return a NumPy array of shape  (1,1) using tanh. Here is what I came up with:

```
import numpy as np
def test_neural(inputs,weights):
    result=np.matmul(inputs,weights)
    print(result)
    z = np.tanh(result)
    return (z)
x = np.array([[1],[1]])
y = np.array([[1],[1]])

z=test_neural(x,y)
print("final result:",z)
```

But I am getting the following matmul error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: You can't matrix multiply to matrices both of shape `(2, 1)` you will need to transpose one so you are multiplying the first with a shape `(1,2)` and the other `(2, 1)`. That will give you a shape of `(1, 1)`.

Comment: This is not a python/numpy-specific problem, but a maths problem.

Comment: `matmul` describes in detail how dimensions should line up.  The key one - last dim of A pairs with 2nd to the last of B, the classic rows with columns of matrix multiplication,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the dimensions of the matrix multiplication.

You can multiply matrixes with shared dimensions like this (read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition)):

```
(M , N) * (N , K) => Result dimensions is (M, K)
```

You try multiply:

```
(2 , 1) * (2, 1)
```

But the dimensions are illegal.

So you have to transpose `inputs` before multiply (just apply `.T` on the matrix), so you get valid dimensions for multiplication:

```
(1, 2) * (2, 1) => Result dimension is (1, 1)
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
def test_neural(inputs,weights):
    result=np.matmul(inputs.T, weights)
    print(result)
    z = np.tanh(result)
    return (z)
x = np.array([[1],[1]])
y = np.array([[1],[1]])

z=test_neural(x,y)

# final result: [[0.96402758]]
print("final result:",z)
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your answer, but can you _please_ stop digging up old, dormant questions by making minor, inconsequential edits? Your revision history is _full of such edits_. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381413/843953

Comment: @Aviv Yaniv - Your comment about transpose was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Why would you post that here? Furthermore, why would you post it at all? Unless the edits are detrimental, (please note if they are), what could possibly be the problem with making minor edits?

Comment: @Kröw did you read the link? This was a long time ago, but I remember there were a lot of edits that added only inconsequential whitespace or formatting changes. Editing a question bumps it up the feed